# Words that you cannot use intensifiers with

Tags: intensifying-adverbs

My question is what is the name for words that intensifiers cannot be used with. Words like unique or impossible. Something cannot be more unique or more impossible than another thing. I forgot the name for these and am very curious.

Comment: Those adjectives that are non-gradable in any sense are sometimes called 'absolute' adjectives.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the word **non-gradable.** [Cambridge Dictionary defines it as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/non-gradable)

> A non-gradable adjective or adverb is one that cannot be used in the comparative or superlative, or that cannot be qualified by words such as 'very' or 'quite'.